# p-value for Shapiro-Wilk is high but data doesn't appear normal

Tags: shapiro-wilk-test, jasp

I'm a beginner at stats and I'm trying to understand p-values for paired t-test and Shapiro-Wilks using the JASP **Moon and Aggression** data set (hope the screenshot resolution is ok - click on the image to zoom in):

My understanding is that the null hypothesis for Shapiro-Wilks is that the data is normal. My Shapiro-Wilks p-value is **>0.05** so I thought I should not reject the null hypothesis.  The data is normal.

However, the plot of the data indicates that the data is not normal?

[image]

Comment: These data look consistent with a Normal distribution to me.  With such a small dataset it's easy to confuse random variability with real differences.  That's why you apply a formal test in the first place: to make sure you are not fooling yourself.

Comment: Thanks @whuber.  I've learnt something new!  If you would like to post this as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.